# Java - Bit manipulation (count number of 1s in number)

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

**Can someone explain to my why this method works**, I've worked through what it does, but why does this work. Is there a pattern that binary numbers have? Like for example at i = 3, why does it do res[1] + 1 to get 2. How does res[3 >> 1] + (3&1) help to count the number of ones in the binary number of 3?

**What the code should do:** It works so don't worry about that. It is supposed to return a list that contains the number of ones in the binary representation of each number until num+1. And num is always >= 0. So for num = 5, you would get [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2], where the last index represents the number of 1s in the binary representation of 5, and the first index is number of ones in binary rep of 0.

**Code:**

```
public int[] countBits(int num) {
        int[] res = new int[num+1];

        for (int i = 0; i<num+1; i++){
            res[i] = res[i >> 1] + (i & 1);
        }

        return res;
    }
```

**This is the part I can't wrap my head around:**

```
res[i] = res[i >> 1] + (i & 1);
```

**EDIT - This is not homework**, so please fully explain your answer. This is to help with interviews.

Comment: Before we try to figure out why it "works", could you explain what it's supposed to do?  I.e. what is the result of `countBits(10)` (for example) supposed to be?

Comment: *Is there a pattern that binary numbers have?* **Yes!**

Comment: @ajb ah sorry, I should have mentioned that, return a list containing the number of ones in numbers 0 to num. So in your case, 0 to 10 inclusive.

Comment: If a number N has binary representation is `abcdefgh`, then `N>>1` has bit pattern `abcdefg` and `N & 1` is the bit `h`.  You should be able to figure it out from there.  If you can't, the best thing to help with your interviews is to study it until you understand.  We aren't being interviewed, so asking us to "fully explain" isn't entirely appropriate.

Comment: It's the bottom-up version of what would be a fairly obvious recursive algorithm. The base case is implemented in a slightly sneaky way.

Comment: @ajb ahhhh that actually makes a lot of sense. For some reason its a bit more clear when given unique characters, rather than 0s and 1s. Thank you!

Comment: @ajb write you answer down, so I can give it best answer, and other people can know as well. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

```
 int[] res = new int[num+1];

    for (int i = 0; i<num+1; i++){
        res[i] = res[i >> 1] + (i & 1);
    }

    return res;
```

rewritten as

```
 int[] res = new int[num+1];

    for (int i = 0; i<num+1; i++){
        x = res[i >> 1];
        y = (i & 1);
        res[i] = x + y;
    }

    return res;
```

Create an array to fit the answers, +1?

for each, starting at the low end.

```
res[0] = res[0] + 0&1 = 0 + 0 = 0;
res[1] = res[0] + 1&1 = 0 + 1 = 1;
res[2] = res[1] + 0&1 = 1 + 0 = 0;
res[3] = res[1] + 1&1 = 1 + 1 = 2;
```

Looking at this pattern, I can see that because of the right shift, and the masking with &, it's splitting the problem into 2, one that's been solved previously due to the iteration order, and a bit check of the last digit.

assuming a 8 bit int, for brevity,

```
1 = 00000001
2 = 00000010
3 = 00000011
```

Split the binary into parts.

```
i    i>>1      y&1
1 = 0000000     1
2 = 0000001     0
3 = 0000001     1
```

So it fetches the results for the number of ones in the first half of the array, then counts the last digit.

Because of the iteration order, and array initialisation values, this is guaranteed to work.

For values < 0 , due to 2's compliment it gets hairy, which is why it only works for values >=0

Answer (score 0):

in 'res[i] = res[i >> 1] + (i & 1);'

one number's result is divide into 2 parts

- the last bit is 1 or not,which can be calculate by (i & 1).
- the first (n-1) bits,this number is equals to res[i >> 1]'s bitcount.this is a simple  recursive call

Answer (score 0):

1. shift by 1 gives the floor number divided by 2.
2. AND 1 returns 1 if the last bit of the number is 1

Hope the below table helps to see what is happening :) Just my 2 cents.

```
<pre>
--------------------------------
<b>
#   8   4   2   1  >>1  &1  Ans
</b>
-------------------------------
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   1   0   1   1
2   0   0   1   0   1   0   1
3   0   0   1   1   1   1   2
4   0   1   0   0   2   0   1
5   0   1   0   1   2   1   2
6   0   1   1   0   3   0   2
7   0   1   1   1   3   1   3
8   1   0   0   0   4   0   1
9   1   0   0   1   4   1   2
10  1   0   1   0   5   0   2
11  1   0   1   1   5   1   3
12  1   1   0   0   6   0   2
13  1   1   0   1   6   1   3
14  1   1   1   0   7   0   3
15  1   1   1   1   7   1   4
</pre>
```